# Animated uiview switches back to its original state when rotating device

Tags: ios, animation, layout, uiview, rotation

I try to make a tiny animation under IOS7. My view controller has 2 views: a tableview and a mapview. I have a button, that switches between 'show map full screen' and 'show map and tableview' state.

Here is my experimental code:

```
float mapNewX =  self.mapView.frame.origin.x == 0 ? 375 : 0;
float mapNewWidth = mapNewX == 0 ? self.view.frame.size.width : self.view.frame.size.width - mapNewX;

[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.1 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^
 {
     CGRect mapViewFrame = self.mapView.frame;
     mapViewFrame.origin.x = (mapNewX);
     mapViewFrame.size.width = mapNewWidth;
     self.mapView.frame = mapViewFrame;
 }
completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     NSLog(@"OK");
 }];
```

It works, but when I rotate my device, it switches back to the original state. So, when I have full map display, when rotating device, it switches back to tableview + mapview on the screen.

The same happens, if I come back from another view controller by navigation controller. If I tap detail disclosure of a map pin, it switches back to the original layout.

What should I do? Thanks very much!

Update: here are the screenshots before/after rotation (some sensitive data is masked out)

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are using the UIView keyframe API. Shouldn't you also add keyframes using `addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:relativeDuration:animations:`?

Comment: I don't thinks so. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Hello @Tom. do you use auto layouts or constraints ?

Comment: Yes, I use them. Thanks Basheer. They are defined in interface builder.

Comment: Then you should consider removing them. And check against the issue again. :)

Comment: I tried it, but the thing same happens. I tested it by removing all of the from my view controller.

Comment: Can you post images of the view before rotation and after rotation ?

Comment: I updated the question with the images

Comment: this is due to autoLayout constrain break the whole think when rotating, U can update the current frame in viewDidlayoutsubview delegate method will fix your issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you loose frame changes after rotation or screen navigation, it probably relates to view controller's layout methods `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or life cycle methods `viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidAppear:`. Check implementations of these methods if you override them.

Because you use auto layout, it's better *to animate its constraints* instead of frames.

As far as I understood, your task is to move left side of a map to reveal a table view underneath (opened/closed states). With autolayout your screen might look as simple as this:

[image]

*(UIImageView view plays a role of a map)*

`UITableView` constraints

- constant width constraint
- top, leading and bottom space to superview constraints set to zero

`UIImageView` constraints

- top, bottom and trailing space to superview constraints set to zero
- leading space to **superview** set to table width (opened state, animate this constraint)

To implement desired effect we need to animate leading space to superview constraint (selected on a the screenshot). We create an outlet to this constraint and change its `constant` property to opened/closed state.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *mapLeadingSpace;
```

Set initial state of the menu before it will appear on screen. We set a default value, but you can restore an appropriate boolean setting from `NSUserDefaults`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.mapLeadingSpace.constant = 0; // default is closed
}
```

Next, toggle animation on bar button press.

```
- (IBAction)toggle:(id)sender
{
    self.mapLeadingSpace.constant = self.mapLeadingSpace.constant == 0
        ? self.tableView.frame.size.width    // opened
        : 0;                                 // closed

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
        [self.imageView layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all, but this was the answer lead me to exactly to the correct way!

Answer (score 1):

Using
`- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation`

Create a variable to indicate whether it is full screen map or split view, then run the routine once rotation is completed? Not sure how hi-tech of a solution that is, but it's what i'd do! :)

Comment: It does not have a smooth feeling when rotating the device, thanks your answer

Comment: Instead of `- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation`, Use `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`.This will animate the views properly/smoothly. As for the switching back issue,like @craig said, use a bool to store which view is open and use that.

Comment: In this case animation is smooth, I have done it, but the main problem remains: if I come back from another view controller by navigation controller, the layout switches back to the original. Yes, I use the property, but the same happens. It could be some problem in aoutolayout.

Comment: Have a strong property for UIButton which stores which of the button is selected - the map or the the map+tableview. when you come back in ViewWillAppear: just check which button is selected and set selected that button.That will load the corresponding view when u select the button right??

Comment: Yes, I also tried that, but it seems also ugly: the original layout flashes for a moment, and than the correct layout comes.

Comment: Do you do that in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`??

Comment: Both, the same happens

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar split views (2 UItableViews), here is how i managed to fix it.

- First, have a global static variable lets call it `static BOOL _isViewSplitted`
  its static so when you push or pop viewContorller is stays in memory.
- Override `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation`
  check your variable here and if YES, split them if NO, just return.
- Also, you have to check (do the same as above) in `viewWillAppear` when the viewController is popped.

Comment: Hopefully it will help you @Tom

Comment: BTW I tried something similar by storing _isViewSplitted in NSUserDefaults

Comment: if you save it in the NSUserDefaults, then you keep doing this even after the app was terminated. Ok, so if you have this variable stored in UserDefaults, add property in your viewController @property(assign) BOOL isViewSplitted;, and populate(form NsUSerDefaults)this property in viewWillAppear, before anything you do for splitting.

Comment: Another problem comes: if I tap detail disclosure of a map pin, it switches back to the original layout :o

Comment: @Tom what the disclosure does ?

Comment: Hides the annotation bubble and popsup another popup. It seems its root  could be something that leads to layout subviews (?). Everything, that lays out the subviews, leads to strange behaviours.

Comment: you can override - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews in your viewController, and then do the split there. Try it out, don't give up :)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably fix this by coding your constraints and then animating them.

Something like this (the values in this code doesn't match the ones in your example):

```
[subview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[parentview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[parentview addSubview:subview];

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subview);
[parentview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[subview]"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:views]];

NSArray *firstConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[subview]"
                                                                    options:0
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                      views:views];
[parentview addConstraints:firstConstraints];
[parentview layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
[parentview removeConstraints:firstConstraints];

NSArray *secondConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-100-[subview]-100-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:views];
[parentview addConstraints:secondConstraints];

subview.superview.wantsLayer = YES;
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext* context) {
    [context setDuration:.3];
    [context setAllowsImplicitAnimation:YES];
    [context setTimingFunction: [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
    [subview layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
} completionHandler:^{
        [[self delegate] createOptionMenuForPDFViewWithInvoice:invoice andSuperView:parentview];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Tom, your big problem (IMHO) is that you are calling this code that you've provided in your question too often.  Every time its going to toggle the map from full screen to split because it makes this decision from where it is now.  Why don't you just have a boolean ivar you check?  you can flip this in your button action to toggle the maps full screen state, then it won't matter if you repeatedly call this code on reorient etc, just alter the condition in your turnery operators at the start there to this new boolean instead of querying whether the map is full screen or not

Comment: Seems logical. My problem is, that I made several projects under IOS, I had only one topic that makes me frustrated and puzzled: view layout things. So far I could solve everything with more static UI-s ( :)) ), but now I have to do it.

Comment: Please try it.   Just declare a BOOL mapViewIsFullScreen variable and check that right at the top there float mapNewX = (mapViewIsFullScreen ) ? .... : ..... ;   Ps you really should work with CGFloat for this type of stuff rather than float, because on arm64 this value will actually be a double, not a float

Answer (score 1):

This question stood a greater chance of being answered relatively quickly without the need for a bounty had the following information been provided in the original post (in general, this might be a good set of guidelines for any post related to layout in iOS):

(1.) is Auto Layout enabled in the storyboard?

(2.) are you using a mixed (hybrid) approach or pure Auto Layout? in other words, which views have their `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `YES`?

(3.) if any layout methods or rotation callback methods are overridden, provide that implementation

(4.) show us your constraints

I was able to figure out the answer to #1 from the comments.

**My answer given the little I know about the problem:**

If you are using Auto Layout on the map view, then setting its frame in the animation block won't permanently re-position the view because the map view's constraints haven't been changed. Instead, update the map view's constraints before the animation block, then send `layoutIfNeeded` to `self.view` inside the animation block.

```
// update constraints…

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for it! I needed the bounty, because it was a serious question for me, without any answers for a period of time, and also I could not understand what the problem exactly was. You are really kind to try to help me!

Answer (score 1):

Also give a try to this in viewDidload of your Viewcontroller class

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```